# Sorting an object by attribute, by an array with that attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to order an array of objects by its "ID" property, the array looks something like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Test"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Another test"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Third test"
    }
];
```

and the 'sorting' array looks like this:

```
var sortingArray = [2,3,1];
```

How do I go about sorting the object array by the sorting array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const sortedData = sortingArray.map(id => data.find(val => val.id === id))
```

Comment: Works fantastically, do you mind explaining this solution?

Comment: well, you actually don't want to sort your data in the spirit of a sorting function, which tells you in which order any two elements have to be set. you have more like a list of ids , and want them replaced by the data element having that id. Array#map does that. replacing each element (from sortingArr) with something else returned from your map function. in the map function you call the Array#find method, which in a nice declarative way looks in your `data` array and returns that element which has the correct id `val.id === id`.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it doesn't 'top off' existing values. So if the 'data' array receives new values, your method of sorting them makes those new records disappear. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: you mean something like `data.push(newElement);` but sortingArray still `[2,3,1]` or you want the sortedData to automatically update when data is changed?

Comment: Assume that data is an array that is representative of RESTful data and that  the sort array is saved in some form of local storage,

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a small function, something like:

```
function sortByKey(array, key) 
{
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        let x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

and use it like:

```
let sorted = sortByKey(data, "id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and `array#filter`

```js
const data = [{id: 1,name: "Test"},{id: 2,name: "Another test"},{id: 3,name: "Third test"}], 
      sortingArray = [2,3,1];

var result = sortingArray.reduce((res, n) => {
  let temp = data.filter(o => o.id === n);
  return res.concat(temp);
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: are you aware that you return an Array of Arrays? use `find()` instead of `filter()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I think  using `filter()` would be better as it will fetch all the `id`s, instead of giving me one result, in case there are multiple object with same id.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a list like that, I usually have a map where I can fetch the items by ID; for quick access.

a quick version would be:

```js
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Test"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Another test"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Third test"
    }
];
var dataById = data.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[item.id] = item, acc), Object.create(null));

//and now using it

var sortingArray = [2,3,1];

var result = sortingArray.map(id => dataById[id]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Downside of this is that the Array and the map need to be held in sync. so every update you make to the Array *(like adding, removing or replacing an object)* you need to also make to the map. Modifying the objects is fine (unless you modify the ID, wich you should never ever ever do)

If there is much fluctuation on the list, I'd wrap it in some object that handles this syncing for me